# Validation error on Role name when running AWS SageMaker linear-learner locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to build a machine learning model locally using AWS SageMaker, but I got a validation error on IAM Role name. Although it's the exact role name that I created on the console.

This is my code

```
    import boto3
    import sagemaker
    from sagemaker import get_execution_role
    from sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator import image_uris
    from sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator import RecordSet

    sess = sagemaker.Session()


    bucket = sagemaker.Session().default_bucket()
    prefix = 'sagemaker/ccard19'

    role ='arn:aws:iam::94911111111542:role/SageMaker-Full-Access '

    container = image_uris.retrieve('linear-learner',boto3.Session().region_name)
    
    # Some other code

   linear = sagemaker.LinearLearner(role=role,
                                               instance_count=1,
                                               instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                                               predictor_type='binary_classifier')
  
  # Some other code

  ### Fit the classifier
  linear.fit([train_records,val_records,test_records], wait=True, logs='All')
```

And this is the error message

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:iam::949010940542:role/SageMaker-Full-Access ' at 'roleArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^arn:aws[a-z\-]*:iam::\d{12}:role/?[a-zA-Z_0-9+=,.@\-_/]+$
```

Any Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **space** in the name. It should be:

```
role ='arn:aws:iam::94911111111542:role/SageMaker-Full-Access'
```

Comment: I just notice it when I tried to move the notebook to the console. Thank you.